# session management in a complex network topology

Tags: session, web-applications, architecture, load-balancing, shiro

There are 2 homogeneous clusters and these fall under a common domain.
cluster1 has different app servers than cluster2.

How to manage session between these clusters? 
How to authenticate cluster1-app-server created sessionId(session) in cluster2-app-server 
or Is there a common place I can create jsessionId(session) and make it not a container specific implementation?

hazlecast or tomcat gives session replication/management inside a homogeneous cluster.
How to take this between clusterS ?
Any data point is much appreciated.
Is shiro suited for this?

Answer (score 0):

Shiro works well within one machine, it keeps a session in memory. Having it authenticate the same session to another place would require setting tokens on the session, which the other machine recognizes and you would have to write custom code for that.

I think you are better of by using some kind of single signon server like CAS.

http://jasig.github.io/cas/4.0.0/index.html

Comment: shiro's sessionDao should do the trick for cluster level session management(not just 1 machine).But, what will happen to the caching it requires, in a cluster of cluster set up?